# If attribute exists change the css

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check if an attribute has a value. If it does have a value I want to change the css.

This is what I tried..

```
if ($('.note').attr('data-user') !== ''){
     $(this).css('color','blue');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `$('.note').attr()` will only return the value of the **first** `.note` element.
2. `$(this)` does not refer to the `.note` element.

You can use `.each` to iterate over all `.note` elements

```
$('.note').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-user')) {
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you! I actually tried .each but I guess I wrote it wrong. Thanks so much.

Comment: This will fail if the attribute doesn't exist at all btw.

Comment: I just noticed that... jQuery should update it's documentation. I assumed it always returns a string. But then I guess you couldn't distinguish between absence and existence but no value. Luckily the fix is easy.

Comment: @Andy: You should really consider accepting one of the other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20696362/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20696305/218196. They are more concise.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is not what you think it is.

Try:

```
   $('.note').css('color', function(_, val){
       //val is the current color, if attribute has value return blue else return current one itself
       return !$(this).attr('data-user') ? val : 'blue';  
       //or
       //return !$(this).data('user') ? val : 'blue';  
   });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dGTLk/)**

Comment: I always like callback solutions. I wasn't sure whether `.css` accepts one and I didn't want to look it up ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.note[data-user]').css('color', 'blue');

// or, if you want to exclude elements with `data-user=""`...
// though ideally, those wouldn't exist in the first place :P

$('.note[data-user]').not('[data-user=""]').css('color', 'blue');
```

If you want it to apply to all such elements all the time, though, it'd be better done in CSS.

```
.note[data-user] { color: blue; }

.note[data-user]:not([data-user=""]) { color: blue; }
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer! (unless the OP wants to exclude empty values as well).

Comment: @FelixKling: Updated to include code for excluding empty values.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check data attribute by following way:

```
$('.note').data('user')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most consistent way of checking from my experience.

```
if (typeof $('.note').attr('data-user') !== 'undefined' && $.trim($('.note').attr('data-user')).length > 0){
     $(this).css('color','blue');
}
```

Essentially, it checks for existence of the attribute first and then whether there is actually a value in it.